# Page_Load in C#

Tags: c#, pageload

I am working with C# web application. I want to know deeply about the page events. Because I thought that the page load event happens first (when a page is requested in browser). But when I tried with commenting the method `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` the page get loaded without error.

Comment: See this article about Asp.Net page lifecycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Your title isn't well. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: page_load event is not fired first

Comment: in page-load you can put in your code, when you comment it out, it does not "not load the page". the html ever gets rendered, you dont have to declare this manually

Comment: Please ensure that you set the [`AutoEventWireup` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a(v=vs.100).aspx) of the `@Page` directive to "true".

Comment: AutoEventWireup="true" is already given.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

off-course your webpage will work even if there is no Page_Load() method. 
Before a Page_Load() events like PreInit, Init() etc are called. Refer to page life cycle.

Page_Load() method is called after a preLoad event. With Page_Load() you can set default values or check for postBacks etc.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 10;
    }
```

write this and put a break-point on int x = 10; watch sender and e.

Answer (score 4):

Every Page object has `nine events`, most of which you will not have to worry about in your day to day dealings with ASP.NET. The three that you will deal with the most are:

```
Page_Init
Page_Load
Page_PreRender
```

They do **execute in the order given above** so make sure to take that into consideration, especially when building custom controls.  The reason you have to keep this in mind is because information might not be available when you expect if you do not deal with it appropriately.

Refer: [Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
1.Page request

2.Start

3.Initialize

4.Load

5.Postback Event Handling

6.Rendering

7.Unload
```

This is the page life cycle.

Load event comes at 4th position.

**You can check details over here:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx